# Why does NSTextField not redraw the background of focused fields?

Tags: objective-c, background-color, nstextfield, redraw

I'm running into a weird problem. I have two [NSTExtField](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html)s representing a username and a password. When I get an incorrect username/password combination, I set an instance variable stating so in the controller of the view containing those two fields. I then use key-value observing to run the following method when the instance variable changes:

```
- (void)handleCredentialsValidityToggle {
    if ([self areCredentialsValid]) {
        [passwordField setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0]];
        [usernameField setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0]];
    } else {
        [passwordField setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:1.0
                                                                    green:1.0
                                                                     blue:0.35
                                                                    alpha:1.0]];
        [usernameField setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:1.0
                                                                    green:1.0
                                                                     blue:0.35
                                                                    alpha:1.0]];
    }
}
```

This works fine as long as a field isn't active. In other words, if I modify the one of the fields, keep it in focus with the cursor inside, and try to authenticate (by clicking a menu item), the field with the focus does not update to the new background color, while the field without the focus does.

In order to see if I could force it to update, I added the following lines to the end of the method:

```
[passwordField drawCell:[passwordField cell]];
[usernameField drawCell:[usernameField cell]];
```

Still no luck. Anyone have any ideas what could be causing this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that it is drawing the editing frame on top of your custom background color.  You can try subclassing `NSTextFieldCell` and overriding `editWithFrame:inView:editor:delegate:event:`.
(And of course make sure that your cell is `setDrawsBackground:YES`.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that! I'll be back to mark your answer as correct as soon as I get it working. :-)

Comment: Well, it's consistent with the behavior that I'm seeing: if I click away from it, the proper background appears. I don't have time to work on it today, but I will soon, so I'll confirm.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it working. Very sad. It seems to have to do with the selection state of the field. Who knows, though?